# Fetching all users in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch all the users in my application so as to pick the user name or id in a select form, but I have not been able to achieve this after a long struggle. My MessageController that retrieves the messages is:

```
public function getMail(){
        $message = Message::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

$pple = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
    var_dump($pple);

            return view('mail', array('user' => $pple))->with('messages', $message, 'users',$pple );
    }
```

My view that I want to render the users is:

```
<div>
<select id="recipient">
   <option>{{$pple->name}}</option>
       </select>
          </div>
```

I have really tried doing this to help me pick up a user **id** or **name** to use in my messaging system.I would appreciate if someone helped me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get your users then pluck to get the result:

```
$messages = Message::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

$users = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->pluck('name', 'id');
```

and return

```
return view('mail')->with(compact('messages', 'users'));
```

Then use it this way in your view

```
<select name="recipient" id="recipient">
    @foreach($users as $id => $name)
        <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $name }}</option>
    @enforeach
</select>
```

Don't forget to add a `name` to your select.

Comment: how should my return statement look like? i have it like this    "return view('mail', array('user' => $pple))->with('messages', $message, 'users',$pple );"

Comment: Made some changes to clarify

Comment: mmh Undefined variable: users (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\dating\resources\views\mail.blade.php)

Comment: You don't need to use `->get()` before `->pluck()`, because Eloquent has it's own `pluck()` method.

Comment: Force of habit ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your view, this should work

```
@foreach($pple as $userId => $userName)
    <option value="{{ $userId }}">{{ $userName }}</option>
@endforeach
```